# (ruby on rails)After an server data update, how to load/display a specific div from a partial in the quickest way with jquery/ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

for clarity purposes I will display all the relevant code files to give the question contest/clarity. I am editing specific divs in a partial with a form and want to display the newly updated div only.

**I have this div on the page Scoreboard#show:**

```
<div class="all-schedules"> 
    <%= render 'schedules/schedules' %>
</div>
```

**The partial _schedules.html.erb**( with `@schedules= @scoreboard.schedules.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)`)

```
 <% @schedules.each do |schedule| %>
      <div class ="schedule-list" id="schedule_<%=schedule.id%>">
         <div class="sched-box-1">
           #various divs here 
           e.g <div class="sched-details"> <%=schedule.detail %></div>
         </div>

         <div class="sched-buttons">
           <span class>
             <%= link_to "Edit", edit_scoreboard_schedule_path(@scoreboard, schedule), remote: true, class: " sched-edit btn btn-primary" %>
           </span>

           <span class> 
             <%= link_to "Del", [@scoreboard, schedule], remote: true, method: :delete, class: " sched-delete btn btn-primary" %>
           </span>
         </div>
      </div> 
    <% end %>

<%= will_paginate @schedules %>
```

**On the click of the edit button**, the below file(edit.js.erb) is fired:

```
$("#schedule_<%=@schedule.id%>").hide(); #the div being edited is hidden
$("#schedule_<%=@schedule.id%>").after("<%= j render 'scheduleedit'%>"); #this renders the edit form where the div used to be
```

Now, what upon submitting the edit form, I want to hide the edit form and then bring back the div(`schedule_<%=schedule.id%>`) with the  new data. If I use .html() to reload the whole **.all-schedules** div in the past, it resets the pagination index and also since the pagination is ajax, it stops working as a result of .html(). My goal is to only affect the specific 
`#schedule_<%=schedule.id%>` div and insert it where it was previous and stay on the page of pagination that the div was on.

So far, this is what the update.js.erb file looks like:

```
$("#edit_schedule_<%=@schedule.id%>").hide(); #this successfully hides the edit form 

#code needed here to re-render the `#schedule_<%=schedule.id%>` div 
#without affecting the ajax pagination and staying on the same page in the pagination index
```

I would prefer to use .html() for this as it is faster than .load(). I don't know if there's any other other methods out there to make this just as quick as .html(). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider moving out the content of one schedule into a partial.

schedules/_schedule.html.erb

```
<div class="schedule-list" id="schedule_<%=schedule.id%>">
   # your content
</div>
```

[Render collection view](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rendering-collections-in-rails) schedules from parent view:

```
<div class="all-schedules"> 
  <%= render @schedules %>
</div>
```

At this point you could easily render the only the schedule you need to reload:

update.js.erb

```
$("#schedule_<%=@schedule.id%>").html("<%= j render('schedules', schedule: @schedule) %>")
```

Give it a try bro ;)

Comment: Dude that is a sweet solution. Your are a champion. Just one small thing, in the update.js.erb it should be 'schedule' instead of 'schedules'. Otherwise, this solution is awesome!!!